# SteamFriends unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors, steam, unreal-engine4, steamworks-api

I have been following the Steamworks documentation to a T, but I am running into linker errors.

I know that the API is installed correctly and imported correctly, because I can include any steam header file and it finds it properly, and when I run my game, the Steam overlay shows up.

However, I recently tried to access the community part of the API, particularly to get the user's friends. According to the documentation, you are to use the SteamFriends() symbol for that.

I have included `steam_api.h`, `steam_gameserver.h`, `isteamfriends.h`, and `isteamutils.h` in my accessing object's header, and I have also added the `steam_api.dll` and `steam_api.lib` to my project, but no dice.

Every time, I get the following error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_SteamFriends

Has anyone successfully done this?

---

### Additional Info:

- Unreal Engine Version: 4.7.5
- Steam API Version: 1.32
- Platform: PC
- IDE: Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scrounging the internet for any documentation, I found the problem.

Epic expects you to link all libraries and perform all includes that you need manually.

This meant that I had to add the directory where all of the `steam_api.lib`, `steam_api64.lib`, etc files were stored to the configuration, and then I needed to link it in the actual files using

```
#pragma comment(lib, "win64/steam_api64")
```

---

So on a side note, they need help with their documentation; that was way harder to figure out than it should be.

Comment: Needing to 'manually' include all libraries is very typical for C and C++ development. Usually this entails the two steps you have figured out: adding the include and library directories to your configuration, and telling the linker which libraries to include.

Comment: You don't understand though. The tutorial that Epic provides for using the Steam API doesn't detail adding much of anything to your project. You simply move files in the engine folders and then tell your project to add a dependency module. They never said anything about having to edit the library paths or having to link libraries.

Comment: Oh, I understand; I've been there. I was just remarking that this is a specific example of a general thing with C and C++ and third-party libraries: if you're using a library, then you need to explicitly include it and unless someone has a pre-built project/makefile/etc. for you, it's your job to keep track of it.